# Unable to get the "first" response with Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

So I am trying to log in to a system using Python Requests module. When I do the post request:

```py
r = requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=payload, verify=False)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.cookies)
```

and I try to print out the cookies, it shows me none. However, in the Burp Suite, I can see that it gets the response with the cookies I need, but it automatically asks for a landing page of the website and for some other stuff (basically it performs 2 more requests using the cookies I got in the first response). So when I ask for the cookies, it shows me cookies of the last response (obviously there are not any).

How can I get cookies from the first request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to set the flag `allow_redirects=False` and check the response for cookies and then follow the redirect manually. Given that it is a redirect that initiates the next request.